# I am making a browser In pyqt5, but I don't know how to place the website content in the browser

Tags: python, pyqt5

[image]

so basically I want the website content to be right under the browser, I don't know how to do that. Basically whichever link you click on, the searchbar should be right there on the top. Right now, I have just made it as the central widget, because I don't know how to put it under the searchbar. Here's the code:

```
import requests
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLineEdit, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


def check_if_url_is_valid(url):
    if not url.startswith("http"):
        return "http://" + url
    elif url.startswith("http") or url.startswith("https"):
        return url


def render_html():
    website = QWebEngineView()
    website.load(QUrl("https://google.com"))
    website.show()


class StealthBrowser(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StealthBrowser, self).__init__()
        self.search = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.textbox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.search_button_clicked1 = False
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.initUi()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 700)
        self.setWindowTitle("StealthBrowser")

    def initUi(self):
        self.textbox.move(20, 20)
        self.search.move(300, 15)
        self.textbox.resize(280, 20)
        self.search.setText("Search")
        self.search.clicked.connect(lambda: self.search_button_clicked())

    def search_button_clicked(self):
        self.render_website()
        print(self.textbox.text())

    def render_website(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(check_if_url_is_valid(self.textbox.text())))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)


def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = StealthBrowser()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


window()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use layouts to position the elements, in this case a QGridLayout.

```py
class StealthBrowser(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StealthBrowser, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 700)
        self.setWindowTitle("StealthBrowser")

        self.search = QPushButton("Search")
        self.textbox = QLineEdit()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()

        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QGridLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.textbox, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.search, 0, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.browser, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.search.clicked.connect(self.search_button_clicked)

    def search_button_clicked(self):
        self.render_website()

    def render_website(self):
        url = QUrl.fromUserInput(self.textbox.text())
        self.browser.load(url)
```