# How do I add a back button and a forward button in pyqt5 to my QGridLayout

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have made a browser in pyqt5. It has a search bar and a button. I want to add a back button and a forward button, just like the ones in regular browsers. Can you also explain how you added it, if you added it, so that I can add my own widgets in the future:) this is the picture of my browser

[image]

so I want the back button and the forward button on the left side of the search bar. Here's the code:

```
class StealthBrowser(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StealthBrowser, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 700)
        self.setWindowTitle("StealthBrowser")
        self.search = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Search")
        self.textbox = QLineEdit()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.backbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Back")
        self.forwardbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Front")
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QGridLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.textbox, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.search, 0, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.browser, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.search.clicked.connect(self.search_button_clicked)
```

Comment: Considering that you're practically posting the same code as in the answer from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67801719), I'd suggest you to carefully read that code, look up the documentation about the classes and [functions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-1) it uses, and patiently *study them*. We're usually glad to explain things, but StackOverflow is not a tutorial website: first of all, do your part and study the documentation, then do some experiments on your own, *finally* come here and ask anything you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `self.backbutton` and `self.forwardbutton` at positions (0,0) and (0,1), respectively, and move all the other widgets over:

```
def initUI(self):
    central_widget = QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
    lay = QGridLayout(central_widget)
    lay.addWidget(self.backbutton, 0, 0)
    lay.addWidget(self.forwardbutton, 0, 1)
    lay.addWidget(self.textbox, 0, 2)
    lay.addWidget(self.search, 0, 3)
    # gridlayout is now 4 widgets wide, so the span of self.browser needs to be increased to 4
    lay.addWidget(self.browser, 1, 0, 1, 4)
    self.search.clicked.connect(self.search_button_clicked)
```

Alternatively you could opt for a combination of a `QHBoxLayout` and `QVBoxLayout` which would allow you to add widgets without having to specify their position in the layout:

```
def initUI2(self):
    central_widget = QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    # create horizontal layout and add buttons and line edit
    hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
    hlayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
    hlayout.addWidget(self.backbutton)
    hlayout.addWidget(self.forwardbutton)
    hlayout.addWidget(self.textbox)
    hlayout.addWidget(self.search)

    # create vertical layout for central widget and add horizontal layout with buttons and the web engine view
    vlayout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
    vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)
    vlayout.addWidget(self.browser)
    self.search.clicked.connect(self.search_button_clicked)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you have to use the layout (in SO there are hundreds of examples in addition to the official examples like https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

You must also use the [`triggerAction()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#triggerAction) method of QWebEnginePage to perform the forward and backward actions.

```py
class StealthBrowser(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StealthBrowser, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 700)
        self.setWindowTitle("StealthBrowser")
        self.search = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Search")
        self.textbox = QLineEdit()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.backbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Back")
        self.forwardbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Front")
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QGridLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.backbutton, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.forwardbutton, 0, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.textbox, 0, 2)
        lay.addWidget(self.search, 0, 3)
        lay.addWidget(self.browser, 1, 0, 1, 4)
        self.search.clicked.connect(self.search_button_clicked)
        self.backbutton.clicked.connect(self.backward)
        self.forwardbutton.clicked.connect(self.forward)

    def backward(self):
        self.browser.page().triggerAction(QWebEnginePage.Back)

    def forward(self):
        self.browser.page().triggerAction(QWebEnginePage.Forward)
```

Note: A browser implementation with Qt already exists so you should check it out as an example:  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-simplebrowser-example.html, which is also written for PySide2 so the conversion to PyQt5 is trivial: https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/tree/examples/webenginewidgets/simplebrowser/simplebrowser.py